# Extension of Liouville's Theorem?

Tags: complex-analysis, analyticity

Liouville's Theorem states that if a function is bounded and holomorphic on the complex plane (i.e. bounded and entire), then it is a constant function.

What if we consider the following, slightly modified scenario:

Suppose a function $f$ is holomorphic and has constant modulus on a bounded domain $D$ (e.g. a small disk).

Can we use Liouville's Theorem to somehow conclude that $f$ is a constant function? (either on $D$ or on the  whole of the complex plane?)

Comment: Maybe not Liouvill, but maximum modulus principle will work.

Comment: Thanks Davide - indeed, this makes it much simpler.

Comment: @DavideGiraudo, can you say more on how to use the maximum modulus principle here?

Comment: A constant modulus on the closure of a domain gives that the function is constant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see how you could use Liouville's theorem to prove that, but it does follow from Cauchy-Riemann's equations.

If you assume that $f$ is entire, use Cauchy-Riemann's equation on $|f|^2 = u^2 + v^2$ to show that both $u$ and $v$ must be constant on $D$. After that it follows from the uniqueness theorem that $f$ is constant everywhere.

Comment: Thanks mrf. Just to clarify - instead of "f is entire," the assumption (as in the original scenario) that f is holomorphic on $D$ will suffice right?

Comment: Yes. (But of course then you only conclude that $f$ is constant on $D$.)